# jquery disable textbox using checkbox (multiple textbox with checkbox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am trying to disable a textbox whenever a user checks the checkbox.

I've done it with a single textbox and checkbox.

I am now stuck what if user can add multiple textbox with checkbox?

Here is what my output looks so far:

[image]

My output has that whenever I tick on the checkbox the disabled attr just toggles on one textbox to another.

I want that when a checkbox was checked the textbox still remains disabled until I uncheck its respective checkbox.

Here is what I coded so far.

**HTML**

```
<div id="operator_properties">
    <label for="operator_title">Operator's title:  </label> <input type="text" id="operator_title">
    <br /><br />
    <button id="append" class="btn btn-primary">Add Connectors</button>
    <br /><br />
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div id="parent"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <hr />
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="operator_btn">
            Confirm
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```js
$(function () {
    var count = 1;
    $('#append').click(function () {
        $('#parent').append('<div class="operator"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" id="input' + count + '" class="input-text" placeholder="Input' + count + ' title"><br /> <input type="checkbox" id="disableinput' + count + '" class="disable-input" /><label for="disableinput' + count + '" style="vertical-align: middle;"> &nbsp; Disable</label> </div> &nbsp <div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" id="output' + count + '" class="output-text" placeholder="Output' + count + ' title"> <a href="#" id="' + count + '" class="remove">Remove</a> <br /> <input type="checkbox" id="disableoutput' + count + '" class="disable-output" /><label for="disableoutput' + count + '"style="vertical-align: middle;"> &nbsp; Disable</label></div></div></div>');
        count++;
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove', function () {
    $(this).closest("div.operator").remove();
});

$(document).on('change', '.disable-input', function () {
    $("#parent").find("input.input-text").attr("disabled", false);
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
        $(this).parent().find("input.input-text").attr("disabled", true);
    //console.log('working');
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the following line:

```
$("#parent").find("input.input-text").attr("disabled", false);
```

...because that's enabling all inputs within the `#parent` element.

You already seem to know how to use `$(this).parent(...).find(...)` to get the textbox related to the clicked item, so just modify that code:

```
$(document).on('change', '.disable-input', function () {
    $(this).parent().find("input.input-text").prop("disabled", this.checked);
});
```

Note that you can simply use `this.checked` rather than `$(this).is(":checked"))` - more efficient and easier to read. Also, use `.prop()` rather than `.attr()` for these sort of dynamic state changes.

Comment: You could even switch the `.parent().find("input.input-text")` with `.siblings("input.input-text")`, because it is on the same level ([see documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/))

Comment: @DouwedeHaan - True. But I actually prefer `.closest(...).find(...)`, rather than `.parent().find(...)` or `.siblings()`, because that way if you decide to modify the HTML to add extra wrapper elements around either element (or move either one inside its label) the JS will continue to work without modification.

Comment: I agree! I think you should even change your answer to that, because that would be more solid!

Answer (score 1):

try this, You were enabling all by setting disabled = false

```
$(function () {
    var count = 1;
    $('#append').click(function () {
        $('#parent').append('<div class="operator"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" id="input' + count + '" class="input-text" placeholder="Input' + count + ' title"><br /> <input type="checkbox" id="disableinput' + count + '" class="disable-input" /><label for="disableinput' + count + '" style="vertical-align: middle;"> &nbsp; Disable</label> </div> &nbsp <div class="col-md-3"><input type="text" id="output' + count + '" class="output-text" placeholder="Output' + count + ' title"> <a href="#" id="' + count + '" class="remove">Remove</a> <br /> <input type="checkbox" id="disableoutput' + count + '" class="disable-output" /><label for="disableoutput' + count + '"style="vertical-align: middle;"> &nbsp; Disable</label></div></div></div>');
        count++;
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove', function () {
    $(this).closest("div.operator").remove();
});

$(document).on('change', '.disable-input', function () {

    //$("#parent").find("input.input-text").attr("disabled", false);
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
        $(this).parent().find("input.input-text").attr("disabled", true);
    }
    else if($(this).not(":checked")){
        $(this).parent().find("input.input-text").attr("disabled", false);
    }
    //console.log('working');
});
```